# AWK syntax error when the variable output has a full stop in it

Tags: bash, awk, syntax-error

I am trying to add this variable (it takes the batch job number and extracts the ID from a text file, with one ID being a new row) so that it can be inputted into the different locations as a variable.

I want this variable outcome (the file ID) to then be added to the start of every entry of the second column of a file.

This is part of the code on LSB (it is working slightly different on that supercomputer than slurm):

```
FILE_ID=$(sed -n "{$LSB_JOBINDEX}p $IDs_file)

awk -v OFS="\t" FILE_ADD=$FILE_ID '{$2="FILE_ADD"$2'}1 $INPUTFILE > $OUTPUTFILE
```

However, I got this error:

```
awk: cmd. line:1: FILE_ADD=ID123.
                                ^ syntax error
```

Thanks!!
Amy

Comment: Oh thank you so much! I did try to look it up but other solutions weren't super clear - thank you!! Amy

Comment: Just running it - will let you know if it works!

Comment: You're missing a closing `"` in `FILE_ID=$(sed -n "{$LSB_JOBINDEX}p $IDs_file)`. Do what the [tag:bash] tag you used instructs - "For shell scripts with syntax or other errors, please check them at https://shellcheck.net before posting them here.".

Comment: @EdMorton Thank you, dear teacher. I would greatly appreciate your kind feedback on my answer.

Comment: @Freeman your answer does show the correct syntax for what the OP is trying to do.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo! I couldn't copy and paste the script across so had to type it out - my bad

Comment: Fix the issues that http://shellcheck.net tells you about and then post a new question if you still have a problem. Also read https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes and [correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the `$2=FILE_ADD $2` part concatenates the `FILE_ADD` variable with the second column (`$2`) in awk and the `1` at the end is a shorthand way to print all the modified rows

check this out :

```
FILE_ID=$(sed -n "{$LSB_JOBINDEX}p" "$IDs_file")

awk -v OFS="\t" -v FILE_ADD="$FILE_ID" '{$2=FILE_ADD $2}1' "$INPUTFILE" > "$OUTPUTFILE"
```

Comment: You could also suggest an enhancement since you never need sed when you're using awk - `awk -v lsb_idx="$LSB_JOBINDEX" -v OFS='\t' 'NR==FNR{if ($0 ~ lsb_idx) file_id=$0; next} {$2=file_id $2}' "$IDs_file" "$INPUTFILE" > "$OUTPUTFILE"`. I expect that could be made more robust but we can't help with that without seeing sample input, output, and the value of `LSB_JOBINDEX` and it'll do what the OPs current sed+awk do.

Comment: @ Freeman your solution worked, thank you lots! @Ed Morton I will look into your solution too as I'm sure I will use it in the future! Thank you both lots